Problem with using google MLKit text recognition v2 for ios (swift) in react native
I wrote a native wrapper for text recognition using Google MLKit for ios in swift language. the recognizing part working fine. but when I use the method in react native (javascript), the catch block is called immediately after then block. am I missing somethin here?. Here are my native swift module files:
ios/Podfile
# To recognize Latin script
pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'

ios/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

ios/OCRTextRecognizer.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(OCRTextRecognizer,NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(runTextRecognition:(NSString)url resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

@end

ios/OCRTextRecognizer.swift
import Foundation

import MLKit
import UIKit


@objc(OCRTextRecognizer)
class OCRTextRecognizer: NSObject{
    
  // When using Latin script recognition SDK
  let latinOptions = TextRecognizerOptions()
  private lazy var textRecognizer = TextRecognizer.textRecognizer(options: latinOptions)
  
  
  @objc(runTextRecognition:resolver:rejecter:)
  func runTextRecognition(_ url:String, resolver resolve:@escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject:@escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    
    
    let imagePath = url
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async{
      if let imagee = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath){
        
        let visionImage = VisionImage(image: imagee)
        visionImage.orientation = imagee.imageOrientation
        
        self.textRecognizer.process(visionImage) {result,error in
          
          guard error == nil, let result = result else {
            // Error handling
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              reject("TEXT_RECOGNITION_ERROR","Error recognition text",error)
            }
            return
          }
          // Recognized text
          var resLines:[String] = []
          for block in result.blocks {
            for line in block.lines {
              resLines.append(line.text)
            }
          }
          let response = ["blocks":resLines]
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            resolve(response)
          }
          
        }
        

      }

    }    
  }
    
  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
    
}

and finally I used the native method in my React Native component like this:
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'

NativeModules.OCRTextRecognizer.runTextRecognition(imagePath)
                .then((response: any) => {
                    console.log('This block called first');
                })
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    console.log('then this block called');
                });

what I expect is when there is a response (recognized texts), only then block called
what I expect is when there is a response (recognized texts), only then block called
